# Unifying Types in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming, unify

I'm kind of stuck with an assignement concerning my exams. I want to find out the types of those two functions by applying the unifying algorithm by hand:

```
map map
(\x -> x >>= (\y -> y))
```

Could someone point me to the right direction? The only ressource I could find until now was the wikipedia entry which is not really aiding me because of the high level of abstraction.

Greetings and thank you.

Comment: This is the most beginner friendly source I've found: http://cs.brown.edu/courses/cs173/2012/book/types.html#(part._.Type_.Inference) and there is also this, which is a more in-depth explanation http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~antoy/Courses/TPFLP/lectures/TYPE/BasicTypechecking.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's just do the first.

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

Now we can write it again with two different names, for clarity:

```
map :: (c -> d) -> [c] -> [d]
```

Now we substitute the second as the first parameter of the first, getting:

```
(a -> b) === (c -> d) -> ([c] -> [d]) (recall the associativity of (->))
a === (c -> d)
b === ([c] -> [d])
```

Now we substitute those type assignments into the remaining portion of the first signature, getting

```
map map :: [c -> d] -> [[c] -> [d]]
```

Clear?

Comment: I think they were asking for an explanation of type unification in general as well.

Comment: Thank you very much. This explenation was exactly what I was searching for. It was the right-associtivity I missed all the time. Great post.

Answer (score 1):

The type of `map` is `map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`. Hence the type of `map foo` is obtained from `[a] -> [b]` by substituting `a` and `b` with what can be derived from `foo`'s type. If, for example, `foo :: t -> t`, you substitute `a = t, b = t` and obtain `[t] -> [t]`. If `foo :: [t] -> Int`, you obtain `[[t]] -> [Int]`.

In your case, the type of `foo` (which is `map`) is `(x -> y) -> [x] -> [y]`. You have to unify that type with `a -> b` to find out what `a` and `b` have to be substituted with. [Note that the function arrow is right-associative, `x -> y -> z = x -> (y -> z)`.]

To find the type of

```
\x -> x >>= (\y -> y)
```

use the known type of `(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`. Ignore the constraint (`Monad m =>`) for now.

As the first argument of `(>>=)`, `x` must have a type `m a` for as yet unknown `m` and `a`. The second argument of `(>>=)` is here the identity,

```
(\y -> y) :: t -> t
```

so you must unify `t -> t` with `a -> m b`. That gives you some information about `a`, namely `a = m b`.

That gives `x :: m (m b)`, and `(\x -> x >>= (\y -> y)) :: type_of_x -> type_of_rhs`.

Finally remember the temporarily forgotten constraint `Monad m =>`.

Comment: Thank you your answer clarified this alot. Thank you so much for your invested time.