# Can someone explain how to unify types(Haskell)?

Tags: haskell, hindley-milner

Can someone explain type unification in Haskell? For example: `snd . snd :: (a1, (a2, c)) -> c`

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYrdn.png)

How do we get to, `(a1, (a2, c)) -> c`, from `snd . snd`?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: This is a very broad question. You will want to find a text or tutorial that covers this as it's a complex subject. This question has been asked before at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17148385/unifying-types-in-haskell

Comment: unify them structurally.

Answer (score 3):

Start with

```
snd :: (x1, y1) -> y1
snd :: (x2, y2) -> y2

(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
```

Applying `(.)` to `snd`, with the following pairings

```
b ~ (x1, y1)
c ~ y1
```

yields

```
-- (.) :: (   b    -> c ) -> (a ->     b   ) -> a -> c
-- snd :: (x1, y1) -> y1
(.) snd ::                   (a -> (x1, y1)) -> a -> y1
```

Now applying this to `snd` again with the following pairings

```
a        ~ (x2, y2)
(x1, y1) ~ y2
```

yields

```
-- (.) snd :: (   a    -> (x1, y1)) -> a -> y1
-- snd ::     (x2, y2) ->     y2
(.) snd snd ::                      (x2, y2) -> y1
```

This obscures where `y1` comes from. But since `~` is *symmetric*, we can replace `y2` with `(x1, y1)` to yield

```
(.) snd snd  :: (x2, (x1, y1)) -> y1
```

which is equivalent to `(a1, (a2, c)) -> c` up to alpha renaming.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helps. I can use this to gain a further understanding.